# where can i get more function about igraph than official tutorial?

Tags: python, igraph

> ```
> def simplify(g):
>     g.simplify(multiple=True, loops=True, combine_edges=None)
>     degree_zero_list=g.vs(_degree_eq=0).indices
>     # 删除
>     g.delete_vertices(degree_zero_list)
>     return g
> ```

I get a function like above. g represent a graph created by igraph. But I don't know the meaning of `g.simplify()` and `g.vs(_degree_eq=0).indices`. Where can I find more material about igraph? I couldn't find the two functions at http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#where-to-go-next.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Python backend of igraph could indeed use some polishing and is in many areas not really sufficient to work directly with it.

In any case, there is a more complete documentation found [here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-module.html) and the [corresponding PDF document](https://igraph.org/python/doc/python-igraph.pdf), which both contain a more concise documentation than the link you posted.

For most functions directly working on graphs, you can probably find the description in the [`GraphBase` class](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html), or the derived [`Graph`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html). Specifically, the `.simplify()` functionality can be found in the [former](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#simplify):

> Simplifies a graph by removing self-loops and/or multiple edges.
>   [...]
>
> Parameters:
>
> - multiple - whether to remove multiple edges.
> - loops - whether to remove loops.
> - combine_edges - specifies how to combine the attributes of multiple edges between the same pair of vertices into a single
>     attribute. [...]

A Vertex Sequence (or `vs`) is its own class, and has some more documentation in its [own respective article](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! It really means a lot to me.

Comment: If you find that an answer solves your question, also make sure to accept it as such.

Comment: Hello, kindhearted. I  still have one question.  What does `g.vs(_degree_eq=0).indices` mean? I have not found the relevant content from the learning materials you gave me.

Comment: It is basically described in [here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html#select), although very convoluted: It searches for all vertices whose argument `_degree` is equal (`_eq`) to `0` and returns those. `.indices` simply gives their identifier, instead of the whole `Vertex` object.